# Select inside Include When Loading Related Data in EF6 Is Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a question on EF 6. I have the following statement inside my data model class, which uses to fetch all the invoices, along with their related data(PurchaseItems, Customer and CustomerAddress).

```
public List<Invoice> GetAllInvoice()
    {
        using (var context = new InvoiceSolutionContext())
        {
           return context.Invoices.Include(p => p.PurchaseItems).Include(c => c.Customer.Select(ca => ca.CustomerAddress)).ToList();

        }
    }
```

The above method has the following using statements in the class.
using Invoicing.DomainModel; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

But the problem is, the Select(ca => ca.CustomerAddress) is not working and giving me the following compilation error.

> 'Customer' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Customer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Following are my classes related to the above problem.

```
 public class Invoice 
{      
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Column("invoiceNumber")]
    [Display(Name = "Invoice Number")]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItems { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("totalCost")]
    [Display(Name = "Total Cost")]
    public decimal TotalCost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("taxTotal")]
    [Display(Name = "Tax Amount")]
    public decimal TaxAmount { get; set; }

    [Column("otherCost")]
    [Display(Name = "Other Cost")]
    public decimal OtherCost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("subTotal")]
    [Display(Name = "Sub Total")]
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }


    #region Foreign Key Ref

    [Column("customerID")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }       

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Column("accountID")]
    public int AccountID { get; set; }

    public Account Account { get; set; }

    #endregion

    [Column("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Column("dateModified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [Column("status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public class PurchaseItem 
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("unitPrice")]
    [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("quantity")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    //foreign key reference
    [Column("invoiceID")]
    public int InvoiceID { get; set; }

    public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }

}

    public class Customer
{    
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }     

    [Required]
    [Column("firstName")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage ="First name must have 250 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Column("lastName")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage ="Last name must have 250 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name ="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("emailAddress")]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage ="Email address must have 255 characters or less")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)] 
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")] 
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("contactNumber")]
    [Display(Name ="Contact Number")]
    public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

    [Column("abn")]
    public string ABN { get; set; }

    [Column("dateCreated")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Column("dateModified")]
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

    [Column("status")]
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public List<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }

    public CustomerAddress CustomerAddress { get; set; }

}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int ID { get; set; }       

    [Required]
    [Column("buildingNumber")]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage ="Building number must have 255 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name ="Building Number")]
    public string BuildingNumber { get; set; }      

    [Required]
    [Column("streetName")]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage ="Street name must have 255 characters or less")]
    [Display(Name ="Street Name")]
    public string StreetName { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    [Column("suburb")]
    [MaxLength(255, ErrorMessage ="Suburb must have 255 characters or less")]
    public string Suburb { get; set; }      

    [Required]
    [Column("state")]
    public string State { get; set; }        

    [Column("postCode")]
    [Display(Name ="Postcode")]
    public int PostCode { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }

}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue in here please ? Appreciate your help on this

EDIT: Below is the class diagram
[image: Class Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` is a Linq expression for collections. Customer is a singular entity. You need to use `Include` for the multiple levels to eager load them:

```
return context.Invoices
    .Include(p => p.PurchaseItems)
    .Include(c => c.Customer.CustomerAddress)
    .ToList();
```

When facing references below collections you can eager load them by name. For instance if PurchaseItems had a Product:

```
return context.Invoices
    .Include(p => p.PurchaseItems)
    .Include("PurchaseItems.Product") // Loads product under each Purchase Item
    .Include(c => c.Customer.CustomerAddress)
    .ToList();
```

I believe this can also be done using `Select`:

```
    .Include(p => p.PurchaseItems.Select(pi => pi.Product))
```

It would work for PurchaseItems because that is a collection, where-as Customer was a singular reference.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Much appreciated. It helped me solved the problem and especially understand it.